# How to upload files using watir-webdriver with ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

The actual HTML code is below and I can't figure out how to make watir-webdriver upload files form array that is created. Script so far is accessing the upload form and stops.

HTML Upload form CODE:

```
<form id="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="/projects/155/documents/upload">
<p> … </p><table role="presentation"> … </table><span id="add-files" class="btn" style="">
          Add file(s)...
        </span><input class="hidden" type="file" multiple="" name="files[]"></input>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Start upload" style="display: none;"></input>
<a class="btn" href="/projects/155"> … </a></form>
```

Ruby script file so far:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "cucumber/formatter/unicode"
require "ruby-progressbar"

@b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-plugins --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-translate]

require_relative "1_login.rb"

@b.div(:class, "main-content-container").link(:text, "TestProject").click
@b.div(:id, "documentsContainer").div(:class, "float-right").link(:class, "btn").click


kolekcija = []
current_dir = "C:/Users/Edgars/Desktop/RubyScripts"
Dir.chdir("C:/Users/Edgars/Desktop/RubyScripts/Testfiles")
#dirname = "C:/Users/edgars.karkis/Desktop/AUTOTESTI/letsmt_UserTest_automation" # <-- JĀMAINA UZ DIREKTORIJU, KUR ATRODAS SKRIPTS

Dir.glob( (current_dir + File.join("DOC","*.*")).force_encoding("UTF-8") ).each { |f| kolekcija.store(f, "doc|docx") }
Dir.glob( (current_dir + File.join("DOCX","*.*")).force_encoding("UTF-8") ).each { |f| kolekcija.store(f, "dox|docx") }
Dir.glob( (current_dir + File.join("HTM","*.*")).force_encoding("UTF-8")).each { |f| kolekcija.store(f, "htm") }

puts ""
puts "Tiek veikta atlasīto failu ielāde..."
progress = ProgressBar.create(:title => "Failu ielāde:", :progress_mark => "|", :format => "%t [%B] %p%%", :total => kolekcija.length)

kolekcija.each do |file|
@file = files[0]
    @b.form(:id, "fileupload").span(:id, "add-files").when_present.click
    @b.form(:id, "fileupload").frame(:index, 0).file_field(:name, "files[]").set(@file) # File absolute path
    @b.form(:id, "fileupload").frame(:index, 0).button(:class, "btn").click
    sleep 5
    progress.increment
end
```

Yes I'm trying to make the script upload multiple files that are stored in array from different directory.

The script isn't uploading anything. I have managed to get it that far that it opens the upload window and doesn't select folder and file name.

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/file_field.rb:13:in `set': No such file or directory -  (Errno::ENOENT)
        from test.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

Code for file upload without array but just for single one:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "cucumber/formatter/unicode"
require "ruby-progressbar"

@b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-plugins --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-translate]

require_relative "1_login.rb"

@b.div(:class, "main-content-container").link(:text, "TestProject").click
#@b.div(:class, "btn").link(:text, "Add file(s)").click
@b.div(:id, "documentsContainer").div(:class, "float-right").link(:class, "btn").click

current_dir = "C:\Users\edgars.karkis\Desktop\TaaS\Automatization"
Dir.chdir("\\\\projekti\\testapps\\AUTOTESTS\\TaaS\\TaaS_testa_kopa\\DOC")

fails = "file1.en.doc"

@b.form(:id, "fileupload").span(:id, "add-files").when_present.click
@b.form(:id, "fileupload").frame(:index, 0).file_field(:name, "files[]").set("#{@fails}")
@b.form(:id, "fileupload").frame(:index, 0).span(:class, "btn").click
```

The single file upload try:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "cucumber/formatter/unicode"
require "ruby-progressbar"

@b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, :switches => %w[--disable-plugins --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-translate]

require_relative "1_login.rb"

@b.div(:class, "main-content-container").link(:text, "TestProject").click
#@b.div(:class, "btn").link(:text, "Add file(s)").click
@b.div(:id, "documentsContainer").div(:class, "float-right").link(:class, "btn").click

current_dir = "C:\Users\edgars.karkis\Desktop\TaaS\Automatization"
Dir.chdir("\\\\projekti\\testapps\\AUTOTESTS\\TaaS\\TaaS_testa_kopa\\DOC")

fails = "file1.en.doc"

@b.form(:id, "fileupload").span(:id, "add-files").when_present.click
@b.form(:id, "fileupload").frame(:index, 0).file_field(:name, "files[]").set("#{@fails}")
@b.form(:id, "fileupload").frame(:index, 0).span(:class, "btn").click
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stops" in "Script so far is accesing the upload form and stops"? Is there an exception? Does the file upload dialog open but does not get inputted? Please give more details on what happens.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Upload multiple files? Does the script work if you try to upload just one file?

Comment: Posted information in the article.

Comment: Based on the exception, the file cannot be found. I believe `fails` needs to be the full path to the file. Did you already try the full path in your first example (since we cannot see what `files[0]` is)?

Comment: I updated the main article with the single file upload try.

Comment: The two single file upload scripts are the same?